# Access Synchronized DE with SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, sql, automation

I want to use script activities within automations instead of query activities, however, I am unsure if I can access the synchronized DEs via SSJS.

I have tried researching this, however, I have been unable to find the answer. I was also unable to find it in the Salesforce developer documentation.

Question:
Is it possible to access synchronized DE with SSJS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can definitely access data from Synchronized Data Extensions using SSJS. Lookups and other functions work in SSJS just like they do in AMPscript. Here's an example of a lookup to the `Contact_Salesforce` Synchronized Data Extension:

```
<script runat="server">
     var dataRows = Platform.Function.LookupRows('Contact_Salesforce','Email','test@email.com');
     if(dataRows && dataRows.length > 0) {
          for(var i=0; i<dataRows.length; i++) {
               Platform.Response.Write(dataRows[i]["Email"]);
          }
     }
</script>
```

If you're running this from a Child BU, remember about the [ent.](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_shared_data_extensions.htm&type=5) prefix.

You won't, however, be able to use any of the `insert`/`update`/`upsert`/`delete` functions, but this is the same limitation that you would have with AMPscript.

You can also use [WSProxy](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_WSProxy_basic_retrieve.htm) with Synchronized Data Extensions, which might be a benefit in case you are working with larger data sets:

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("core", "1.1.1");
var deName = "Contact_Salesforce"
var cols = ["Id", "Email"]
var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
var data = prox.retrieve("DataExtensionObject[" + deName + "]", cols);
Write(Stringify(data));
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, that answers my question. The “ent” prefix is also recognized in SSJS.

Comment: Glad it does - please remember to mark the question as answered :-)

Comment: Did you get this to work with synced data extensions? I could not. I tried it so many different ways...